# environment variable dont confirmed

Tags: java, environment-variables, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and JDK 1.6.0 and Eclipse 4.2

after installing JDK on my system i set the environments variables on `/etc/profiles`

```
# file /etc/profiles
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

I think its necessity a system reboot to apply this changes so I reboot the System

Problem: After rebooting the command `java -version` give me this

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

So I find this solution on net that i apply the changes of variables environment like this

```
. /etc/profiles
```

After the precedent command, `java -version` give me the good result

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Its OK and eclipse work but Problem is I must do the command `. /etc/profiles` `before` any program use `java` like SQL Developer or IReport

So I want an idea to `confirm` this variables environments one time of all

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables section System-wide environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Ubuntu machine to test with, but I would try changing

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

to

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/profile`  not  `/etc/profiles`